# Does the date command affect the result of gettimeofday()?

Tags: linux, time

Usually, we call function `gettimeofday` to get current of system.
What will happen if user change clock using the `date` command?
Does it affect the result of function `gettimeofday` or not?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday):

> The time returned by gettimeofday() is affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time (e.g., if the system administrator manually changes the system time). If you need a monotonically increasing clock, see clock_gettime(2).

So, yes, it is.

Comment: Thanks Aconcagua, I will try to use clock_gettime

Comment: Be sure to use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` as first parameter, as `CLOCK_REALTIME` is affected by the same issues as `gettimeofday` function.